Save AudioBuffer from Tone.js to webm
I'm getting a ToneAudioBuffer from Offline rendering of audio (I'm taking voice narration and adding a pre-defined set of effects)
There doesn't seem to be any documentation of how to turn that into a Blob so I can save it as a file.
const audioBuffer = await Offline(async (context) => {
  const player = new Player(source);
  context.transport.start();
  await player.start();
}, sourceDuration);

audioBuffer???

I don't want to use MediaRecorder to avoid waiting for the audio to actually play, that's why I'm using Offline
